# how long a browser is caching an ajax response

Tags: angularjs, ajax, caching, browser-cache

I'm trying to find out how long a browser is caching an ajax response.

I can see from the dev tools network tab in Chrome that the resource is coming `(from disk cache)`, but is there anyway I can see how long it's being held in the cache for and when it will expire?

The resource that is being cached is a HTML file fetched by ajax, an angularJS template.

From testing, it seems to only be cached for an hour or two, but how can I check for sure?

Also where is this cache stored?  Is it on the client's PC, in their chrome/firefox/browser application directory?

### UPDATE

Following on from @Andrew Shepherd answer, I don't see a value for the Cache Control header.

```
Accept-Ranges:none
Connection:close
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:702
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Sat, 25 Feb 2017 01:59:20 GMT
ETag:"eb7-549504ee7ac60-gzip"
Last-Modified:Sat, 25 Feb 2017 00:55:53 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

[image]

Perhaps this has something to do with how the server is set up to cache 'text/html', is their a default time set to cache `text/html` resources?

I can see cache controll on images though...

```
Accept-Ranges:none
Age:64
Cache-Control:public, max-age=899
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Language:en-
Content-Length:4120
Content-Type:image/jpeg;charset=UTF-8
Date:Sat, 25 Feb 2017 01:58:16 GMT
Expires:Sat, 25 Feb 2017 02:13:16 GMT
Last-Modified:Fri, 17 Feb 2017 10:00:23 GMT
X-Cache:HIT
X-Cache-Hits:2
X-dmg-elapsed-time:18ms
X-dmg-generated-time:Sat, 25 Feb 2017 01:58:16 GMT
X-dmg-host-address:172.16.0.64
X-dmg-node-name:fbde_node_4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can know the length of time it would be cached for:

- In your Chrome browser, bring up the F12 developer tools
- Activate the Network tab
- Check 'Disable Cache'
- Refresh the web page
- You will now see every HTTP request that occurs while building the page. Click on the one that interests you
- Activate the 'Headers' tab

Under *Response Headers*, you will see the value for the [Cache Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) header. This should give you all of the details as to how this item will be cached.

[image: Cache Control Header Value]

Comment: thanks but that doesn't appear for me though, I updated my question with some more details.  Also what does `max-age=120` mean, is it 120min?

Comment: No, it means 120 seconds. Your browser is sending an ETag header to the server, which causes the server to compare its ETag with your ETag. If the ETag hasn't changed, then the server returns a 304 Not Modified.

Comment: @Daniel how long does it normally take for the ETag to referesh, it seems to take a couple of hours once I change the file on the server.

Comment: @Holy You never know. Because there's no expiration date on etagged stuff. That's why the control over caching headers is important. The question is specific only to server side, it has nothing to do with Angular. If you have specific problems with undesirable caching in Angular app, I would suggest to ask a new question that reflects the problem.